# How to print signed hexadecimal in C

Tags: c, hex

I know we can use `printf("%04X", value);` to print unsigned hexadecimal values.

Is there a similar flag or a function in C that you can use to print signed hex values?

Something similar like this

```
Binary   Hex (signed) Hex (unsigned)
-------- ----------- --------------

00000010 +0x2        0x2
00000001 +0x1        0x1
00000000 +0x0        0x0
11111111 -0x1        0xFF
11111110 -0x2        0xFE
11111101 -0x3        0xFD
```

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately C's `printf` function has no way to do this directly. You could of course instead try:

```
printf("%s%x\n", x<0 ? "-" : "", x<0 ? -(unsigned)x : x);
```

This should also work for handling INT_MIN.

Comment: wuahhh, now thats a ugly hack... Isn't there anything other, not even in C99?
if not: Damn you, C.

Comment: Please, write `unsigned int` istead of `unsigned` or use `typedef`. Your code is extremely ugly and confusing.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can do something like

```
printf("%c%04X", (x<0) ? '-' : ' ', (x<0) ?-x : x);
```

But, as other point out, it is doubtful whether there is a valid reason to do so. According to your post, you do understand what you're asking for, so it's all your fault ;-)

Comment: If you don't like bugs and obfuscation, you could simply do `if(x<0) printf("-")` before printing the number. Because you have two possible bugs in your code.

Comment: First possible bug: `(x<0)?'-':' '` passes an int to printf, not a char as expected. This is because the 2nd and 3rd operand of the ?: operator are balanced. Both operands are therefore subject to implicit integer promotions. This is especially bad in C++, where character literals are of type char, and not int as in C.

Comment: Second possible bug: `(x<0)?-x:x` If x is signed, the code doesn't make sense to use unary - operator, because x would already be in the desired format. If x is unsigned, it still doesn't make sense to use unary -, since the result is an unsigned type. And even if you managed to get the 2nd operand of ?: to a signed type, it would still be balanced back to an unsigned type, because of the 3rd operand.

Comment: @Lundin: It's not obfuscation. Consider the case where the format string is much longer and involves 4 hex values to be printed as signed. Would you like an if/else tree of 16 `printf` statements, or a single `printf` statement that handles the whole thing?

Comment: @Lundin: And you second and third comment are just **horribly wrong**. `'-'` has type `int` in C to begin with, not `char`. And it's impossible to pass type `char` to a variadic function. `%c` expects an argument of type `int`. As for the third comment, of course the unary `-` operator makes sense on signed values. And **signed** does not mean the same thing as **negative**. It means (roughly) possessing a characteristic of being positive or negative. At this point I think you should stop commenting and find yourself a good book on the C language...

Comment: @R.. Or maybe you are just reading **horribly bad**. Yes I know the type of char literals in C, that may just be why I wrote `"...and not int as in C"`. The problem is that had they been C++ char literals, they would be integer promoted with possible change of signedness. Where in my comments do I use the word negative? You are making this up. I merely pointed out that the result of the unary minus is a promoted type. At this point I think you should stop commenting and pick a good book on the English language.

Comment: (1) this is C, not C++. They are completely different languages. (2) Even in C++, variadic functions are subject to default promotions. It's always impossible to pass `char` to `printf`. As for the issue with negative, you claimed for `(x<0)?-x:x`, "If x is signed, the code doesn't make sense to use unary - operator, because x would already be in the desired format.". I'm not sure what you meant by "format", but `x` does not have the desired *value*, which is what matters here.. Moreover, `(x<0)?-x:x` always has the same signedness (unsigned vs signed) as simply `x`.

Comment: The only thing worth commenting on is about introducing extra function call to avoid what is perceived by commenter as an obfuscation. Actually, I don't think it worth commenting on anymore…
Well, if I were to improve the code, I'd probably redo it as `printf((x<0)?"-%04X":"%04X",...);`, but I think it would be perceived as an even worse obfuscation ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker If an extra function call is critical to your performance, you shouldn't be using stdio.h in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdib.h>
...
printf("%c%#x\n", "+-"[x < 0], (unsigned)abs(x));
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution.  I have never seen indexing into a constant string inline like that before "+-"[ x < 0].  Of course it does depend on the value of true being 1.  Perhaps "+-"[x < 0 ? 1 :0].  I have added this to my bag of tricks now.  Maybe one day I will find a place to use it.  Thanks!

Comment: @AshleyDuncan: You can count on it! comparison operators are defined to evaluate to `0` or `1` in C. `"+-"[x < 0 ? 1 : 0]` would be redundant. Note that this expression could also be written in a more obfuscated style: `(x < 0)["+-"]`.

Comment: Even better solution, performance-wise: `printf("%c%#x\n", "+-"[x < 0], x & 0x7FFFFFFF);` - no unnecessary function call, so faster than `abs()`.

Comment: @chqrlie I don't get the obfuscated style, please, explain! It does not make any sense =\

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer: `(x < 0)["+-"]` is the same as `*((x < 0) + "+-")`, which can be rewritten `*("+-" + (x < 0))`, which is the same as `"+-"[(x < 0)]` or `"+-"[x < 0]`. To make a long story short, however surprising it may be, `a[b]` like `a+b` is commutative in C. Note however that it is not fully associative because of potential signed overflow issues as well as limited floating point precision.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer: also `x & 0x7FFFFFFF` is not equivalent to `(unsigned)abs(x)` except on obsolete architectures that use sign/magnitude representation.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by a "signed" hexadecimal value? Do you want something like "`-e0`"? If so, what would that mean? The sign is already represented in the hexadecimal display, since it shows all the bits and that's all the information that's in the number.

Comment: Well, it can be interpreted as value in hexadecimal with sign in front of it. Whether one may want it for valid reason is another issue :)