# Printing out negative hexadecimals

Tags: c, printf, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to print signed hex in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602974/how-to-print-signed-hex-in-c)

I am trying to print out hexadecimal numbers numbers.

The variable wich I am trying to print out is of type `int i`, and when I:

```
printf("%06X", i);
```

it always give me 8 digits if the number is negative and 6 if positive.

It does not matter if I change the `"%06"`, to `"%04"` or something else I always get 8 digits if the value is negative.

Comment: And what is your question? What result do you expect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602974/how-to-print-signed-hex-in-c

Comment: when you use %x,%X, printf expects unsigned integer.

Comment: I want the format 000001 if i = 1 and FFFFFF if i = -1 (always 6 digits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “6” in “%06X” specifies the minimum number of digits to print. The conversion will print more if more are needed to show the full value. The “0” says to use leading zeroes, rather than the default of spaces, if the value is smaller than the minimum number of digits requested.

You are getting eight digits because the “X” specifier is for an `unsigned int` argument. There are no negative `unsigned int` values. Your C implementation is reinterpreting the bits that encode a negative `int` as an unsigned `int`. For example, the `int` value -1 is stored, in 32-bit two’s complement form, as 0xffffffff. So the format conversion sees an `unsigned int` with the high bits set, and it uses all the digits it needs to display them.

There are several changes you can or should make:

First, you should not pass an `int` for a specifier that expects `unsigned int`. You should convert the `int` to an `unsigned int` with a cast, as in `(unsigned int) i`.

Second, you should pass the value you want printed. If you want only the low six hexadecimal digits printed, you can pass just those digits by using a mask with an AND operator: `printf("%06X", (unsigned int) i & 0xffffff)`.

Alternatively, if you want to print a signed hexadecimal value, then you must handle the sign yourself, as with:

```
if (0 <= i)
    printf(" %06X", (unsigned int)  i);
else
    printf("-%06X", (unsigned int) -i);
```

(The latter presumes that `i` is never a large enough negative value that `-i` overflows. If `-i` could overflow, simple modifications are available to get the desired behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

Negative numbers are stored represented in binary using [2's Complement](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binary_numbers#2.27s_Complement). This means, that negative numbers, in binary, has leading 1's. Play around with [this calculator](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_signed_int.html) to get a better feel of it.

If you ask `printf` to format a number using `%X` the number will be treated as unsigned. If you treat a binary representation of a negative number ignoring the possibility that I may be a negative numbers, i.e., disregarding the leading 1's as a sign that it is a negative number, then you can only evaluate that the number is actually bigger.

The `06` part tells `printf` to pad the number with leading 0's up to six digits. Of course, if the number already has more than 6 digits, this is irrelevant.