# negative integer/float decimal number to signed hex and octal in standard C code

Tags: c, hex, decimal, signed, octal

How do you turn a negative decimal number to a signed octal/hex number.

This is a portion of my code and its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>


int main()
{

signed short int sui1 = -127;

printf("+------------+-----+-----+------------+------------+------------+");
printf("------------+------------+\n");
printf("%s %11s %6s %5s %12s" , "Type", "Var", "Size", "Dec.", "Hex."  );
printf("%13s %10s %14s", "Oct.", "FP", "Exp\n");


printf("%s %10s %4i %6i %#14x" , "char", "c1", sizeof(c1), c1, c1); 
printf("%#13o %10f %22e\n", c1, c1, c1);

return 0;
}
```

the output for my octal and hexadecimal do not have a negative number like I was hoping, any suggestions?

decimal= -128

octal=0177601

hex=0xff81

Comment: Hex and octal are for humans, making it obvious what the bits in the value look like.  And it is obvious that the high bit is set so it is a negative value.  Producing a "signed hex string" would just obfuscate that information.

Comment: What *is* your expected output for –128 in hex?  Is it `-0xff81`, `-0x80` or something completely different?

Comment: I suppose Iam definitely expecting the first output I am very confused.

Comment: See Michael Krelin's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602974/how-to-print-signed-hex-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the example below for the binary number in **8-bits** to make things more clear :

```
11111111
```

if it is a considered as a signed number then the decimal value will be  -1

```
11111111
||||||||---> +1*2^0
|||||||----> +1*2^1
||||||-----> +1*2^2
|||||------> +1*2^3
||||-------> +1*2^4
|||--------> +1*2^5
||---------> +1*2^6
|----------> -1*2^7
             -------
               -1
```

because the left most bit will be considered as a sign bit and taken as negative, but the rest (first 7 bits) will stay always positive, when getting the value in **base 10** as it is shown above

if it is an unsigned bit than all the bits will be **positive** to get the value in **base 10** whic is 255

```
11111111
||||||||---> +1*2^0
|||||||----> +1*2^1
||||||-----> +1*2^2
|||||------> +1*2^3
||||-------> +1*2^4
|||--------> +1*2^5
||---------> +1*2^6
|----------> +1*2^7
             -------
               255
```

and as you can see the binary number `11111111` is the same in binary notation for signed and unsigned, (even in octal notation (`0377`) and hexadecimal notation (`0xFF`)) but different in decimal notation which depends on what you consider it as a signed number or unsigned number

Here is a program that converts signed decimal to hexadecimal and octal notation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int nb;
    printf("please enter the decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d",&nb);
    char octal[100]="",hex[100]="";
    //octal will hold the octal notation 
    //hex will hold the hexadecimal notation
    sprintf(octal,"%#o",nb); //convert decimal to octal 
    sprintf(hex,"%#X",nb); // convert decimal to hexadecimal 

    // show the result 
    printf("converting %d to hexadecimal notation %s\n",nb,hex);
    printf("converting %d to octal notation %s\n",nb,octal);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `"%o"` and `"%x"` format specifiers expect `unsigned` matching arguments.  So even if code passes an `signed short int` with a negative value, that value is eventual converted to `unsigned` before printing.  Thus only positive values (and 0) are printed.

To print a negative number in base-16 (or base-8 with `"%o"`), code could use;

```
signed short int sui1 = -127;
printf("%c%x", sui1 < 0 ? '-' : '+', (unsigned) abs(sui1));
```